# iOS 5 - Is there a way to disable autofill in a UITextView but keep the spell check (red underline)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, autocorrect

It seems like setting **autocorrectionType** either enables or disables both (1) the autofill of words as you type and (2) the red underline as you misspell a word.

In the Settings App, there are separate sliders for "Auto-Correct" and "Check Spelling".

I am wondering if there is any way (possibly via workaround) to keep misspelled words underlined in the UITextView but not autofill programmatically using Objective-C?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is also a "spellCheckingType" property:

```
[textView setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[textView setSpellCheckingType:UITextSpellCheckingTypeYes];
```

I tried this and it will not autocorrect, but it leaves the red lines and suggestions.